# How to stop scrolling effect for background image

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a page with a background image and some stuff above it. The stuff above fits exactly in the screen size and that doesn't need a scroll. But because of the background image being large scroll was appearing. How to fix it?

```css
#bg-img {
  filter: blur(8px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.bg-text {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/opacity/see-through */
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  top: 32%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<v-content>
  <!-- <v-container> -->
  <v-layout @click="closeform">
    <v-flex>
      <img id="bg-img" class="white--text" height="100%" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/set-badminton-shuttlecock-feather-professional-450w-1030859371.jpg"/>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
  <v-container grid-list-md text-xs-center class="bg-text" @click="closeform">
    <h2>Hey </h2>
  </v-container>
</v-content>
```

Comment: Can u provide the code?

Comment: @Evil_Sperm: You have to post the code what you had tried so we can easily understand to solve your problem.

Comment: I tried your code in codepen and i cant see the background image,
anyways have you tried 'background-position: contain;' ???

Comment: @JoykalInfotech That didn't work :(

Comment: Here is the result of your code (changed `<v-img>` to `<img/>`) :https://codverter.com/src/webeditor?query=411ffcb7-95a6-4f92-b530-b0a26db5a9de I can not see the problem that you are describing.

Comment: Actually inside v-container there is other thing, as that is a little confidential i put "hey" there. What i need is a scroll for 'bg-text' rather than scroll for 'bg-img'

Comment: You seemingly use some sort of code HTML generation template thing which I do not recognise. It would be preferable, if you  posted the resulting HTML code here, as that is, what matters and this way we all might see the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can use background-position property,

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Comment: @Evil_Sperm use position:fixed property.

Comment: When changed to fixed image was dissappearing

Answer (score 0):

none of the `background` properties will work it is an `<img/>` tag. You need to use `background-image` for that.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  background-image: url(https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/set-badminton-shuttlecock-feather-professional-450w-1030859371.jpg);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}

.bg-text {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/opacity/see-through */
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  top: 32%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<v-content>
  <!-- <v-container> -->
  <v-container grid-list-md text-xs-center class="bg-text" @click="closeform">
    <h2>Hey </h2>
  </v-container>
</v-content>
```

Comment: You can see that scroll is appearing. But that shouldn't appear as image is big, scroll should appear only for text if required.

Comment: @Evil_Sperm no i added `margin:300px auto;`. I removed this line

Answer (score 0):

```
div {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height: 90vh;
}

<div style="background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1548707519-f5221b5a5fd8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1265&q=80');"></div>
```